# NodeJS library for text search of files in a directory

Tags: node.js

I have multiple folders on the server containing around 10,000 files (JSON files) and I am looking for a NodeJS library that could select files that matches the search criteria. That library could alleviate the pain of doing sync/async file reads and 'grep'ing the content.

I came across JS libraries like Flaxsearch, Elasticlunr etc. but I am not sure if they would work with file system based content.